# How can I make a div with "position:fixed" to stay out of the screen if the window overflows?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position, screen-size

I have two divs as in the illustration below. The position of div #2 is fixed, so it sticks to the right side of the screen no matter how small it might be. If the screen is small, then the div #2 starts to overlap over div #1, which I do not want. I know that this problem is being caused because the left and right positions of both divs are in percentages, but they must stay in percentages only. I can work around this problem using Javascript, but I was thinking of a pure CSS solution for the users who may have Javascript disabled.

```
+---------+ +---------+
|         | |         |
|         | |         |
|   #1    | |    #2   |
|         | |         |
|         | |         |
+---------+ +---------+
```

What's happening if the screen is small:

```
+------ +---------+
|       |         |
|       |         |
|   #1  |    #2   |
|       |         |
|       |         |
+------ +---------+
-------scrollbar---
```

What should happen (screen ends where the scrollbar ends):

```
+---------+ +------
|         | |      
|         | |      
|   #1    | |    #2
|         | |      
|         | |      
+---------+ +------
------scrollbar----
```

Comment: when you use percent as unit, why do you use position:fixed? Why don't you just float the divs?

Comment: Why don't you just float them against each other with a min width?

Comment: div #2 is supposed to be of fixed position, so it can stick to page as the user scrolls down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `margin` to position your div #2 rather than `position: fixed`.

Comment: and if the OP wants his `div` to be fixed? i.e. you scroll down

Answer (score 0):

If u dont want to use float. try using instead `right:` you can give a `left:` value to the #2 div ...